# No CSS working in my Rails 4 app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am running Rails 4.1.8 on Windows 7 64-bit. Editor is RubyMine.

I had some elementary Bootstrap styling going (table-striped, buttons) but the glyphicons were not working. I tried to switch to bootstrap-sass and messed things up, so...

I am now trying to get back to pure use of bootstrap without the sass complication or any gems. I can't seem to make use of the styles in bootstrap.min, however.

In fact, *nothing* from my css files is getting applied to my pages.

[image: My assets folders]

My application.css file contains:

```css
/*
*= require bootstrap.min
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
 */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

I have uninstalled the bootstrap-sass and rails-sass gems, so I should be using only the css files local to the project.

My Gemfile:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'

# Use PostgreSQL as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '0.18.0.pre20141117110243'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use turbolinks to speed up link navigation
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'uglifier' # compression

gem 'pony' # easier email

group :development do
   gem 'thin' # light-weight web server
   gem 'letter_opener' # view emails locally without sending
   gem 'dotenv-rails' # load ENV vars from .env file
   gem 'debase'
end

# Need time zone info
gem 'tzinfo-data'

group :production do
   gem 'rails_12factor'
   gem 'unicorn'
end
```

I ran bundle update at one point (by mistake), so I have the latest version of everything.

I have run bundle install several times, cleared the Firefox cache and restarted Firefox.

I'm probably missing something basic after working on this for some hours now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by switching from

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css">
```

...to the helper style...

```html
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

My guess is that this format is smarter about relative paths to assets.